# WMI programming to find job id

Tags: windows, installation, wmi, nsis

I am trying to find out the job id's by passing command line argument using WMI.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

```
// Initialize COM.
hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. " 
        << "Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    return 1;              // Program has failed.
}

// Initialize 
hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,     
    -1,      // COM negotiates service                  
    NULL,    // Authentication services
    NULL,    // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,    // authentication
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // Impersonation
    NULL,             // Authentication info 
    EOAC_NONE,        // Additional capabilities
    NULL              // Reserved
    );


if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize security. " 
        << "Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;          // Program has failed.
}

// Obtain the initial locator to Windows Management
// on a particular host computer.
IWbemLocator *pLoc = 0;

hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,             
    0, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. "
        << "Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;       // Program has failed.
}

IWbemServices *pSvc = 0;

// Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with the
// current user and obtain pointer pSvc
// to make IWbemServices calls.

hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(

    _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // WMI namespace
    NULL,                    // User name
    NULL,                    // User password
    0,                       // Locale
    NULL,                    // Security flags                 
    0,                       // Authority       
    0,                       // Context object
    &pSvc                    // IWbemServices proxy
    );                              

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                // Program has failed.
}

cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;

// Set the IWbemServices proxy so that impersonation
// of the user (client) occurs.
hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(

   pSvc,                         // the proxy to set
   RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,            // authentication service
   RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,             // authorization service
   NULL,                         // Server principal name
   RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,       // authentication level
   RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // impersonation level
   NULL,                         // client identity 
   EOAC_NONE                     // proxy capabilities     
);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}


// Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI. 
// Make requests here:

// For example, query for all the running processes
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where CommandLine like 'commandLineString'"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);
cout << " After execquery"<< endl ;
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for processes failed. "
         << "Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}
else
{ 
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

       VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hres = pclsObj->Get(L"ProcessId", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        int processId = (int)vtProp.intVal;
        cout << "Process ID : " << processId << endl;           

        DWORD dwProcessId = (DWORD) processId;
        DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_TERMINATE;
        BOOL  bInheritHandle  = FALSE;
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
        if (hProcess == NULL)
        {
            cout << "hProcess is null " << endl;
        }else {
        BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 1);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        cout << "Process is terminated " << result <<endl;
        }
    }  // while          
 } // else  

// Cleanup
// ========

pLoc->Release();
pSvc->Release();
CoUninitialize();
getchar();
return 0; // Program successfully completed.
```

}

Above is the C++ code and my question is how do I access structure in nsis.
like the below lines in above code

```
1. hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
2. hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
3. hres = pclsObj->Get
```

Please help me on this...

Comment: They are not structures, they are methods in a COM interface...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [WmiInspector](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WmiInspector_plug-in) plugin? Alternatively use your existing C++ code to create a [custom plugin](http://nsis.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nsis/NSIS/trunk/Contrib/ExDLL/exdll.c?view=markup).

To call the Windows API or a COM interface in NSIS you have to use the system plugin:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER 0x1
!define CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI {1968106d-f3b5-44cf-890e-116fcb9ecef1}
!define IID_IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI {1f76a169-f994-40ac-8fc8-0959e8874710} ;[Vista+]

section
;NSIS has called CoInitialize
System::Call 'OLE32::CoCreateInstance(g "${CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI}",i 0,i ${CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER},g "${IID_IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI}",*i.r1)i.r0' ;ptr is now in $1 and hr in $0
${If} $1 <> 0
    System::Call '$1->3(w "Internet Explorer")i.r0' ;IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI
    System::Call '$1->2()' ;IUnknown::Release
${EndIf}
sectionend
```

You have to manually look up IIDs and the vtable offset for methods so using a lot of COM is not going to be fun...

Comment: I meant accessing methods from the structures. using like this $1->3 is like hardcoding isn't it? Is there any alternate way of calling using System Plugin (which is there in 2.46 release). Could you please tel me in detail of "-> 3" means

Comment: $1->2() in system syntax means: $1 is the address of the interface, -> means this is a call to a COM method and 2 is the method offset in the vtable (Queryinterface=0, AddRef=1, Release=2 and the first non-IUnknown method is 3). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/05/68017.aspx for more...

Comment: For a slightly better way of calling COM see http://nsis.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nsis/NSIS/trunk/Include/Win/COM.nsh?view=markup (You would have to change all p types to i for 2.46)